# Virtual drive not showing up in client machine for initial 15 mins

Tags: c#, powershell, networking, vfs

I am facing this problem where I cant see the virtual drives mounted on my host machine in client (VM) for initial 15 mins (approximate).

This is what I am doing.

1. using `dokkan.exe` to set up 2 virtual drives I and J on host machine (coded in c# exe)
2. Spin up 2 virtual machines on the host machine
3. Trying to access the virtual drives from client machine, it doesnt show up I and J but I can see c and d drives which are on the  host.

leaving it for few minutes(close to 15 mins or so) I can now access both the virtual drives.

When i use powershell to do this, I get  network connection issue. Really appreciate if anyone faced this before and how to solve this problem.

**ERROR details**

> 3/9/2019 1:10:46 PM Mapping network drives from host into client
>   machine ... The network connection could not be found. At
>   D:\data\setupscript.ps1:376 char:2
>   +     Invoke-Command -VMName $clName -Credential $localCreds -ScriptBlo ...
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The network con...d not be found.:String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
>       + PSComputerName        : mycomput1

**Script**

```
Invoke-Command -VMName $clName -Credential $localCreds -ScriptBlock {
        net use I: /Delete /y
        net use I: "\\$hostIp\i$" /persistent:yes
        net use J: /Delete /y
        net use J: "\\$hostIp\j$" /persistent:yes
    }
```